# Is it possible to search thru an array of objects in one line without predicates?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to find if a specific element exists in a collection. Elements are objects with properties.
I need to do it without predicates and or for/while loops.

If I were to do it with predicates, it would be simple:

```
array.Any(n=>n.SomeProperty > 100)
```

Is this possible to do at all?

Comment: What is your *real* business requirement. Without explanation the artificial constraint of no predicates comes across as absurd.

Comment: I'm trying to use Dynamic Expresso to evaluate string-based expressions.  Dynamic Expresso does not support predicates

Comment: Why not just present the user with the full C# language, and instead restrict the libraries/namespaces to which they can link?

Comment: Can you not write a function in real C# that searches an array by your particular property, and then give Dynamic Expresso access to that function?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Can't open full C#, because it's not secure

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm pondering this approach now.  Problem is, expressions and elements are dynamic... so, I dont know at compile time what element looks like

Comment: What's not secure about the *language* C#? You can simply disable access to namespaces such as System.Reflection by not providing them to the compiler.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like:

```
var dynamicExpression = "SomeProperty > 100"
array.Any(n=> EvaluateExpression(dynamicExpression, v));

bool EvaluateExpression(string expression, double value){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Going with this albeit somewhat modified